# How to add a MailChimp Sign Up form for a Newsletter to a website

Tags: forms, mailchimp

I am using MailChimp for sending out Newsletters but I would like to add a MailChimp Sign Up form to the website on the Home page.

How do I do this?

I am extremely new to this product so thank you for any help you can provide.
Regards

Comment: Thank you for your question. It isn't clear this question has anything to do with ExpressionEngine, so you might want to clarify that you are using EE, and what version you are using, or your question might get flagged as off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Yes, the website is created using EE.  I am unable to locate what version we are using.  I would have gone to our developer, but he has closed his business down and we are unable to contact him.

Comment: I think your best bet is to seek out / hire another developer to help you; this is a developer forum and I doubt we can answer your question without a lot more information that you may not be able to provide. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

We did this in a template in pure html, so we did not use any Expression-Engine-Tags for this (although you might be able to use a form-builder-addon like [EEHarbor Forms](https://eeharbor.com/forms), but I see no reason for this in the actual case).

The most important ressource you will find in Mailchimp: Select your list, then the "Signup Forms". With "embedded forms" you will be able to generate html-code for a form, different options available.

The form could look somehow like this:

```
<form id="newsletter_form" method="post" action="//yourmailchimpname.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post">
    <input type="hidden" name="u" value="checkMailchimpFormBuilder">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="checkMailchimpFormBuilder">

    <button value="1" type="submit">Send</button>
    <label for="email" name="email"><b>Email</b>
        <input required="" name="MERGE0" type="email" autocomplete="off" pattern="(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}">
    </label>
</form>
```